# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied How do I fix this?

Tags: python

Iam newbie to python and keep on getting this error when run this script, I have given full permission to the file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/usr/local/bin/ftp_site.py", line 3, in <module>
        import anprint
      File "/usr/local/bin/anprint.py", line 17, in <module>
        hdlr = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 897, in __init__
        StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 916, in _open
        stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/anpr_log'
```

I have recently upgraded from MYSQL to mariadb.

```
Script : anprint.py





def all_in_cam_ids_by_site_id(self,site_id):
    ret_list =[]
    sql = """SELECT .......WHERE carparks.id = "%s" AND in_out = 1 """ % site_id
    ret_val = self.cursor.execute(sql)
    if (ret_val > 0):
        ret_array = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for retId in ret_array:
            ret_list.append(retId[0])
    else:
        logging.error("No Cameras for Site id %s", site_id)

    return ret_list
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /tmp/anpr_log` ?

Comment: sudo chmod 755 /tmp/

Comment: @MuraliMopuru 1777 should be better... but that changes only the `/tmp` permissions, not the ones of the said file.

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx , I tried everything but still getting the same error.

Comment: ERROR:root:No camera with id 272
ERROR:root:No camera with id 271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script has no permission to write into log file. Changing `chmod` of `tmp/anpr_log` should fix your issue:

```
sudo chmod +rw /tmp/anpr_log
```

Comment: I tried your command and when I run it again i get  ERROR:root:No camera with id 272
ERROR:root:No camera with id 271

Comment: What if you run `sudo chmod 777 /tmp/anpr_log` ?Would you have same error ? I think you would have same error, because now you have another problem, which is probably another question as it's related to other things..

Comment: now you have another problem, which is probably another question as it's related to other errors... answer above is answer to your initial question.